# Version issuess while installing node packages

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

[image]I'm trying to install mongoose, But I'm facing this warning. I have cross checked the version which I'm using. Do I have to reinstall node again or is there any other solution?

Comment: Update node version to 12+. Let's say install nvm and provide .nvmrc file with `v>=16.20.1`, then nvm use

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it in a new terminal or restarting your system.
Try installing packages without the **sudo** command.
If nothing helps then use `nvm` to install node versions.